# The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired

Tags: xml, vimeo

I'm trying to add the vimeo [`getByTag`](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getByTag) to my `rma` application.

```
vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=xml&method=vimeo.test.login&oauth_consumer_key=456b2fecee2080ed734a1357467e0fd9d9e1e2bb&oauth_nonce=35bf1a696da9e26ac8f9dbcf866fc938&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1352889238&oauth_token=08387a1bfa80277c6e7f79436bf57113&oauth_signature=kvuC%2Fp8jxgcyRHAkjNN7q%2FOVldI%3D&oauth_version=1.0
```

When I paste the upper link into my URL bar, I get the following errors:

```
The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired
or
The oauth_nonce passed has already been used
```

Instead of the XML result you can see when you try out the method.

Comment: we need to see some code that handles the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-use OAuth urls - if you could, there would be replay attacks possible.  As the error says: "The oauth_nonce passed has already been used"

You need to read up on OAuth a bit, then read this: http://zinclabs.com/VimeoAPIforPHP.html

If you're not using PHP, you'll need to do the same steps using one of the community-developed API wrappers.